# How to add default values in one table when create the schema

Tags: laravel, symfony, orm, doctrine

How to add default records in table when creating the schema in the console with `doctrine` / `symfony`

When i run `php bin/console doctrine:database:create` command i need create a default user with some values.

Answer (score 2):

You need to load database fixtures. For sample you can do it with DoctrineFixturesBundle ([Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html))

Answer (score 2):

You could create a fixtures for import default data. You can found examples in this [page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#writing-simple-fixtures).

Answer (score 1):

Best way to add user seeder

```
$data = array(
['name' => 'abc', 'email' => 'abc@gmail.com', 
'password' => '$2y$10$e3wJ0gt7unM/wPm1LKPx']);

DB::table('user')->insert($data);
```

For more information
check https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/seeding